# Parse missing value in JSON as unit-struct

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

Unit structs don't have a value, however serde is unable to parse them from missing values. I have to explicitly set the value to `null`. For example:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json::json;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct SomeStruct;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type", content = "config")]
pub enum Value {
    Fixed(String),
    FromMatch { foo: String, bar: SomeStruct },
}

fn main() {
    let config_json = json!({
        "type": "FromMatch",
        "config": {
            "foo": "foo",
        }
    });

    let _config: Value = serde_json::from_value(config_json).unwrap();
}
```

If I run the above I get the following error: `"missing field 'bar'"`, even though `bar` doesn't need a value. However if I change the json to:

```rust
let config_json = json!({
    "type": "FromMatch",
    "config": {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": null
    }
});
```

This runs fine. Is there someway I can parse missing values into unit structs correctly?

Comment: https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#skip

Answer (score 0):

Derive or implement `Default` for your structure and then mark the field with [`#[serde(skip)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#skip).